# Moving a background image randomly and smoothly

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed background image attached to the body tag, the image is 2048px by 2048px and is top centered:

```
body {
   background: url(images/background.jpg) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed;
}
```

I want to add some movement to the background so it pans around the entire image while the viewers are navigating the site

Using: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js to normalize the background-position property, I can animate the image as follows:

```
$('body').animate({
    backgroundPositionX: '100%',
    backgroundPositionY: '100%'
}, 10000, 'linear');
```

Instead of going to the bottom right in 10 seconds, I want to add random movement.

Using set interval I can can animate the image every 10 seconds, but how do I determine the background position percentages? When the image moves it should be the same speed, just random locations

```
var currX = 50;
var currY = 0;

$(function () {
    animate();

    window.setInterval(animate(), 10000);
});

function animate() {
    var newPosX = currX - (Math.random() * 50);
    var newPosY = currY - (Math.random() * 50);

    $('body').animate({
        backgroundPositionX: newPosX + '%',
        backgroundPositionY: newPosY + '%'
    }, 10000, 'linear');
}
```

EDIT: a fiddle to better describe what I want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/97w7f3c8/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an example of how it could be done. Random direction is selected by random angle, then checkup that destination does not go out of range from 0 to 100 (may be not necessary)

```js
$(function() {
     var p = [0, 0], speed = 10, runMe = function () {
        var angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        var d = [
            speed * Math.cos(angle), 
            speed * Math.sin(angle)
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
           p[i] = (p[i] + d[i] > 100 || p[i] + d[i] < 0) ? p[i] - d[i] : p[i] + d[i];

        $('body').animate({
            backgroundPositionX: p[0] + '%',
            backgroundPositionY: p[1] + '%'
        }, 5000, 'linear', runMe);
     };
    
     runMe();
});
```

```css
body {
 background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @user3023421 I made a small correction, angle should be the same for both coordinates, so that speed will be constant.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 now [supports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) background transitions natively as shown below. `bgpos.js` isn't needed. Also, in my experience, this performs much better on mobile devices — the movement is smooth without choppiness. I think it's because native CSS transitions allows for hardware acceleration.

```
body {
    background: url(../img/mypic.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: 0s linear;
    transition-property: background-position;
}
```

```
var defaultTime = 10000;

var x1 = 50, y1 = 50, moveBackground = function() {

    var x2 = Math.random() * 100;
    var y2 = Math.random() * 100;

    // pythagorean theorem
    var distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2)+ Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2) );

    var time = defaultTime * (distance / 100);

    $('body').css({
        'transition-duration': time + 'ms',
        'background-position': x2+'% '+y2+'%'
    });

    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;

    setTimeout(moveBackground, time);
};

moveBackground();
```